# Can't access the internal pages on CodeIgniter coded website

Tags: codeigniter

I have a website design prototype coded in Code Igniter 2.0 and I can't access the internal pages.

Here's the link to the website prototype: http://thepbe.org/

When I try to access internal pages, the browser just displays "No input file specified."

I think there's something wrong with my .htaccess file.

Here's the code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Comment: yes try this link: http://thepbe.org/articles/read/6/true

Comment: you cant access any internal page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `application/config/config.php` file and make sure these options are set.

```
$config['index_page'] = “”;
$config['uri_protocol'] = “AUTO“;
```

then change your .htaccess file to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to absence of .htaccess file or incomplete .htaccess file.

You can use below code for .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```